# avoid factorygirl repeate the number when run second time in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

Its my factorygirl code

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :account do
      sequence :name do |n|
        "Test Account#{n}"
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my method for run factorygirl code

```
  def create_accounts n=2
    n.times do
      FactoryGirl.create(:account, subscription_ids: @sub.id.to_s)
    end
  end
```

My problem is, first time my FactoryGirl output is `Test Account1, Test Account2`, When i execute second time, It create output as `Test Account3, Test Account4`. But I need `Test Account1, Test Account2` when run multiple time. How may i do this.

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem after replace this code

```
def create_accounts n=1
  create_subscription
  n.times do |r|
    r += 1
    FactoryGirl.create(:account, subscription_ids: @sub.id.to_s, name: "Test Account#{r}")
  end
end
```

**Updated**

I am using cucumber-> capybara -> selenium

Reset the factory girl sequence

add this code in spec->support->reset.rb

```
module FactoryGirl
  def self.reload
    self.factories.clear
    self.sequences.clear
    self.traits.clear
    self.find_definitions
  end
end
```

Add this in env.rb

```
After do 
  FactoryGirl.reload 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

FactoryGirl is designed to create new unique records every time you call `#create`. If you want to keep the original record set around, you should save them to a variable and then return them rather than running FactoryGirl.create again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem to clean the database after every test. This helps to prevent any problems rising from the state of the database.

Comment: I am already using in my project. Thank you so much. If I have any doubt in database_cleaner, I will ask you. :)